# Iphone 12 zoom in while taking photo without cropping

Tags: iphone

I just took a picture with my Iphone 12 and I zoomed in while taking the photo to see if the focus was sharp. When I looked at the photo I expected to see the whole photo but instead it only saved the part that was visible during shooting.

Is it possible to have the whole picture saved and not just the part that is visible on the screen? I often zoom in with my DSLR to check the focus better, but it always saves the whole picture.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know all contemporary phones use this zoom function to "change" the focal length, not as preview for photographer. Next time do not do it if your intention is to preview. And check it after the fact.